# Open function : how to protect against directory opening?

Tags: c

I am using the open function like this in my file to get some coordinates from a file :

```
t_coo       *get_buffer(char **av, t_coo **head)
{
    int     ret;
    int     fd;
    char    *line;
    int     y;
    t_coo   *cur;

    cur = NULL;
    *head = NULL;
    y = 0;
    ret = 0;
    fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
    while ((ret = get_next_line(fd, &line) > 0))
    {
        head = get_map(line, head, y);
        y++;
    }
    close(fd);
    cur = *head;
    return (cur);
}
```

It is working perfectly but the problem is when I try to make it open a directory, my program segfault. I want to protect it against directory opening so that I dont segault anymore. I tried to look at the flags on the internet and tried many of them but I could not find this one. Can anybody tell me which one it is? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `opendir` or `scandir` is what you are looking for? If you want to prevent opening a dir in your list, then you can use `stat` to check the type.

Comment: fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY | O_SCANDIR); does not work at all

Comment: I would like a flag from the open function

Comment: Also look at `access ( d, F_OK )` or `fd = open (name, O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);`

Comment: Instead of checking whether it *isn't* a directory, check if it *is* a (properly formatted) file: fix `get_next_line` and/or `get_map` so they don't crash on unexpected data from the 'file' being `open`ed. The segfault probably comes from `get_next_line` or `get_map` which fail on unexpected data. Even if you make sure to not `open` a directory, it could still be a character device, or socket or just an improperly formatted file. Protect against that instead.

Comment: how do I check if fd is a file or a directory ?

Comment: @zakk8889: with `fstat` as I have answered

Comment: Always check for errors!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `lstat` function to tell you whether the given file name represents a regular file or a directory.

```
struct stat statbuf;
int rval;

rval = lstat(argv[1], &statbuf);
if (rval == -1) {
    perror("error getting file status");
    exit(1);
}

if (S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    printf("%s is a regular file\n", argv[1]);
} else if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    printf("%s is a directory\n", argv[1]);
} else {
    printf("%s is something else\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to make it protected with a flag from the open function. Like the O_RDONLY flag

Comment: @zakk8889 Then you're out of luck, because there's no such flag.

Comment: I have been told there is, I will let you know if I find out :)

Comment: @zakk8889 If there is, it's very OS specific.  Linux doesn't define such a flag.  Using `lstat` or `fstat` is the way it is done.

Comment: That introduces a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to `open`  the file (which could be a directory) so get a file descriptor, then use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) on that file descriptor (and check the result of `fstat` by using  `statresult.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFDIR` ...)

This would avoid an (improbable) race condition with the `lstat` (or `stat`) then `open` approach (suggested in [Dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756790/841108)): some other process might (with very bad luck) remove or rename the file between these two system calls. You might also [opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) or else `open`  (but that also suffers from a similar race condition).

<sup>PS. The race conditions I am suggesting here are so improbable that we can normally ignore them... But they might be a security flaw (than an attacker could use)</sup>

Comment: "PS. The race conditions I am suggesting here are so improbable that we can ignore them..." - yes, normally. But if you allow them, then someone will cause one deliberately to make your program crash.